# Is there a way to search for keyboard layouts by characters on specific buttons?

Tags: keyboard-layout, arabic

I have a Dell Inspiron 7520 SE, bought it here in Egypt. I need to install the English and Arabic language layouts but I've spent too much time trying numerous different layouts and nothings worked perfectly, I get 2-3 misplaced characters at best.

Is there an way by which I can filter out layouts by specific characters for specific buttons ?

For example, can I specify a button location and search for layouts that output a specific character which this button is clicked ? Of course I need to do this for multiple buttons to be able to zero in the best layout for me.

I read the layout [editing\customization guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) but it sounded VERY complicated and I can't risk messing anything with my current setup.

Comment: I found [this websites] to be VERY helpful. I got this link from [this answer][1].


  [1]: http://superuser.com/a/685631/149496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964651.aspx) to be VERY helpful. I got it from [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/685631/149496).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an way by which I can filter out layouts by specific characters for specific buttons ?

There is. But apparently is only available during the installation:

[image]

You could install ubiquity package and simulate an installation to find the correct layout you need.

Comment: Thanks, I used it during the installation but it didn't give me the best layout though. Also do you know if the character displayed in the wizard which is similar to the double quotes, is actually double quotes ? `"`. It's more like 2 single quotes next to each other, and they look very close to each other `''`

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana should be double quotes. Other than that is check them all.

Comment: What do you mean by `check them all` ?

Comment: Check one by one until you find your desired layout?

Comment: I have already went through A LOT. Thanks for the ubiquity package, I hope it solves this. Is there a chance that my layout just isn't in the list ?

Comment: Is weird, but *could* happen.